# How to replace all occurrences of string one by one (loop)

Tags: php, string, loops, str-replace

I have string with x occurrences of some substring. I need replace every occurrences of substring one by one (not all at one step) and everytime when I replace one substring, i need save  this substring into variable before it will be replaced...

Exactly - I have input with text and three images in base64. I need cut base64 code of images (replace it with '') and save this img base64 code into new file and echo only input text without base64 code of imgs...

I tried for loops, while loops, functions... but everytime it replace only first occurrences of substring and not other

I think that I must save $original_string every time in loop cycle, because in my codes it always start with whole $original_string from input. But I don't know how I must do it...

```php
$img_count = substr_count($original_string, "data:image");

for ($i = 0; $i < $img_count; $i++) {
    $img_name = get_string_between($original_string, 'data-filename="', '.');
    $img_base64 = get_string_between($original_string, 'src="', '"');
    $original_string = str_replace($img_base64, '', $original_string);

    $myfile = fopen("../img/clanky/" . $id_noveho_clanku . "/" . $img_name . ".txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = $img_base64;
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

```php
while (strpos($original_string, "data:image") !== false) {
    $img_name = get_string_between($original_string, 'data-filename="', '.');
    $img_base64 = get_string_between($original_string, 'src="', '"');
    $original_string = str_replace($img_base64, '', $original_string);

    $myfile = fopen("../img/clanky/" . $id_noveho_clanku . "/" . $img_name . ".txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = $img_base64;
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

I want to have 3 files with base64 code of images and twxt from input without this base64. But I have only one file, and text without only first occurrence.

EDIT:
so, I find out this...

I upload img "výstřižek.jpg", On my web img are render correctly, without errors.  if I see on my admin site on webhosting, I see this name correctly in files, but if I connect to my host server by filezilla FTP and I open file tree in this FTP client, there I see "VÃÂ½stÃÂiÃÂ¾ek3.jpg". But why??

I cant post images here, so I upload screenshots on gdrive, please view them, for better understood of actual problem
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OQn-L1xePo6o1I6U7mmvZbxiEOBhPLvp

Comment: You could `explode` by the `substr` that you are looking for, and then loop through the created array and build out your new array / strings from there.

Comment: Also -- It would be nice to have an example of what your original string looks like, and what your intended results look like ..

Comment: OK, I edited the post and add some screenshots. I hope that it will be helpful for you and you can solved my problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your code always returns the first result because it's always matching from the beginning of the string, you should remove the part you've already processed for it to work or use an offset from which to start the search in each iterarion: start with `0` and before removing the data, use its position as the next offset. You would then have to pass it to your `get_string_between` function to limit the search.

But since your original string is in fact html, I'd recommend using some html parsing library to avoid headaches with attributes being on a different order, possible escaping issues, etc. This solution uses the [DOM extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.installation.php) that should be enabled by default.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
// Treat the string as a frament and do not add a DOCTYPE or mandatory tags 
$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($original_string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

// Get all images
$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    $src = $img->getAttribute('src');
    $name = $img->getAttribute('data-filename');

    // Check if it contains base64 data and a filename
    if (false !== mb_strpos($src, 'data:image') && "" !== $name) {
        $data = mb_substr($src, strpos($src, ',') + 1); // Data start
        $img->setAttribute('src', mb_str_replace($data, '', $src)); // Remove data

        $name = mb_substr($name, 0, strrpos($name, '.'));
        // Save the image to disk
        $path = "../img/clanky/${id_noveho_clanku}/${name}.txt";
        file_put_contents($path, $data);            
    }
}

// Get the HTML with the data removed
$parsed = $doc->saveHTML($doc);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/CXKkH)

Comment: OK, this works. thank you. But how can I change charset of this part of code?

for whole .php file i have charset-utf8 (i need support Czech and other languages) and on whole site its ok, but only if i upload img with some name like as "výstřižek.jpg" your code dont recognize this chars and save it into db like this "VÃÂ½stÃÂiÃÂ¾ek3"  so, how can i set charset-utf8 for your part of code? or where is problem?  table in tb is set for utf8 and on other site of this web i can upload img with this names without problems....

Comment: @MatějKopecký Updated the `loadHTML` call to properly convert the encoding to utf.

Comment: @MatějKopecký Just be aware that when using that method the `<?xml?>` tag will be present in the `$parsed` output.

Comment: EDIT::

I solved it by this

$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $original_string, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);



EDIT2:

this not save img name correctly...   Yes, in db is sorrect name "výstřižek.jpg", but file which is upload on server still have name like this "VÃÂ½stÃÂiÃÂ¾ek3.jpg". On site imgs are rendered correctly, but in server files their names are wrong...  how can I set utf8 for upload (fopen() / fwrite() etc) ??

Comment: I cant post images here, so I upload screenshots on gdrive, please view them, for better understood of actual problem https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OQn-L1xePo6o1I6U7mmvZbxiEOBhPLvp

Comment: @MatějKopecký Transferring through ftp to windows is going to give you headaches since it uses a different encoding. See [here](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Character_Encoding). Look in the log, it says "Server nepodporuje... ASCII", the server doesn't seem to support the UTF extensions or it's disabled in your client. If you could zip the directory I think that will take care of transforming the encoding on uncompression.

Comment: I search on internet and I solved it...  

in filezilla FTP client is encoding set as Automatic,  and I use windows 10 with utf8 czech language, czech webhosting server with utf8, in my php files is set utf8, so I was think that it automatic set utf8 in my client, but apparently no..

So I change settings from Automatic to Enforced utf8 and it works - Now i see correct names of files in my ftp client.

So i hope that this is all, and my problem is completely solved.

Thank you very much once more for your helpful advices and codes!!